# ReactJS API request failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, fetch-api

I am developing a react app using Spring Boot backend.
I am not very friendly with Java or Spring Boot and now I am stuck with an issue.

Bellow is backend method code which is handling the request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/toys")
public class ToysController {

@Autowired
private ToysService toysService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@PostMapping("/addtoy")
public ResponseEntity<Toys> addToy(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("toyName") String toyName,
        @RequestParam("toyDescription") String toyDescription,
        @RequestParam("toyPrice") Long toyPrice,
        @RequestParam("quantity") int quantity,
        @RequestParam("availability") Boolean availability,
        @RequestParam("sellerId") Long sellerId) throws IOException{
    Toys toy = new Toys();
    toy.setToyName(toyName);
    toy.setToyDescription(toyDescription);
    toy.setQuantity(quantity);
    toy.setToyPrice(toyPrice);
    toy.setAvailability(availability);
    toy.setSellerId(sellerId);
    toy.setToyImage(ImageEncoderDecoder.compressBytes(file.getBytes()));
    toy.setImageName(file.getOriginalFilename());
    
    Toys toyRes = toysService.addToy(toy);

    if(toyRes!=null) {
        toyRes.setToyImage(ImageEncoderDecoder.decompressBytes(toyRes.getToyImage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Toys>(toyRes,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        return new ResponseEntity<Toys>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
}
```

Below are the request details I am supposed to use

```
API: http://localhost:8081/toys/addtoy
Method: POST
Body:
[{"key":"toyName","value":"Car","type":"text","enabled":true}, 
{"key":"toyDescription","value":"small car 6 month old","type":"text","enabled":true}, 
{"key":"toyPrice","value":"600","type":"text","enabled":true}, 
{"key":"quantity","value":"2","type":"text","enabled":true}, 
{"key":"availability","value":"true","type":"text","enabled":true}, 
{"key":"file","type":"file","enabled":true,"value":[]}, 
{"key":"sellerId","value":"1","type":"text","enabled":true}]
Response: Status code 200
```

Following is how I am trying to hit the API

```
export const addToy = toy => {
const requestOptions = {
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=%%",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' 
    },
    body: toy
};

fetch(`${API}/toys/addtoy`, requestOptions)  // API = 'http://localhost:8081'
.then(response => {
    if(response.status === 200)
        console.log('Toy Inserted');
    console.log('Resopose : ', response);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error while inserting toy : ', err);
}) 
}
```

Calling the above method

```
    const handleSubmit = e => {

        e.preventDefault()

        let formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('toyName', toyName)
        formData.append('toyDescription', toyDesc)
        formData.append('toyPrice', parseInt(toyPrice))
        formData.append('quantity', parseInt(toyQty))
        formData.append('availability', parseInt(toyQty) > 0)
        formData.append('file', image)
        formData.append('sellerId', parseInt(loggedIn.loggedInUser.userId))

        addToy(formData)
    }
```

The response I am getting back

```
body: ReadableStream
    locked: false
    bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8081/toys/addtoy"
```

Comment: "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=%%",
must be the issue. i am suggesting using it as 2 API's
one for image upload and the other for data. data API must be application/json

Comment: Actually, I am developing frontend only. The backend guy did his work and now he is totally out of the picture. So I have to do it with the same API

Comment: I guess that we need some logs of the API in order to help you.